# Apache storm Kafka SpoutConfig for Zookeeper quorum

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

To configure a `kafkaSpout`, it Takes `BrokerHosts` which in turn take one zookeeper host.

```
BrokerHosts host = new ZkHosts("server-1:2181");

SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(host, TopologyConstants.KAFKA_QUEUE.SOURCE,
            "/" + TopologyConstants.KAFKA_QUEUE.SOURCE, ID);

KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
```

Problem is, If i have a zookeeper quorum(cluster of 3 zk servers), how do i configure `KafkaSpout` to take all the members of quorum instead of only 1.
As one zookeeper server may get down and the whole topology will be unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to my question:
connection string format is `"host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3..."` (storm-kafka uses Curator under the hood), so just supply multiple Zookeeper server urls to the ZkHosts constructor